# Basic indentation settings in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tabs, settings

The default settings in Xcode 3.2.6 do some automatic indentation: typing `if (something)` and pressing return (when the cursor is to the right of the closing paren) automatically indents the cursor by one tab.  **How can I turn this feature off?**

I tried turning off "syntax-aware indenting" however this doesn't solve the problem.  Pressing return in the above example still indents the cursor (it's aligned with `if` in this case).

My ultimate **goal** is to avoid "stray tabs" (blank lines that have tabs).

Comment: Don't worry about it.  When you get to Xcode 4 everything will change anyway.  (And what real harm do "stray tabs" cause?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook in a code beautifier to clean up the tabs afterwards: http://robertjpayne.com/post/9092159751/using-uncrustify-directly-in-xcode-4